# Retrieve URL scheme with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, mobile, browser, url-scheme

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the URL scheme of a browser application using javascript (on mobile)?

For example: 
You're browsing a web page on your phone using Google Chrome. Would it be possible for that page to run some javascript and retrieve the googlechrome:// scheme?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I just found out that the 'navigator' object has a method called 'registerProtocolHandler' which lets websites register themselves as possible handlers for particular protocols.

This comes pretty close to what I need. The only problem is that this requires permission from the person who is visiting the website, which doesn't compliment the flow I'm going for. Also, it doesn't support Safari on iOS..

Comment: This won't work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Nope. 'Location' gives a lot of useful information like the protocol, hash, pathname etc. But it doesn't give me the scheme (googlechrome://)

Comment: I didn't know there was a `googlechrome://` scheme... Browsers use standard HTTP schemes. Even if you did use some weird scheme, `Location` would be able to tell you what it is. Where is `googlechrome://` documented?

Comment: Apps on phones have custom schemes like whatsapp:// or googlechrome://. This way you can open them from within other applications. Here are some docs about Google Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links

Comment: I also found another useful link that shows the schemes for the major browsers: https://gist.github.com/felquis/a08ee196747f71689dcb. The problem is that I don't want to hardcode them. I want to retrieve them through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By the time your JavaScript is running on the webpage, the user's phone has used the URI Scheme (say `googlechrome://`) to choose a web browser it has installed. The browser then requests your site using a web protocol like `http://`. This is what [`window.location.protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/protocol) will provide.

So, JavaScript isn't aware of 'schemes' in the sense of 'browser applications'.

However, you can figure out the user's browser from their [User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) and then deduce a possible URI scheme from this. Still, you can't be certain the user didn't just open up Chrome and navigate to your site themselves, without ever tapping a link.

Note that user agents are not always [reliable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent):

> users of a browser can change the value of this field if they want (UA spoofing).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Xander. So the only way to do this is to map all the possible browsers to their corresponding scheme based on an unreliable User Agent? I feel like this stuff should be included into the window object..

Comment: Yes. What is your use case?

Comment: A person who visits a website using a phone, clicks on a link, and will be redirected to an app installed on their phone. The app fetches some information and redirects the person back to the corresponding website. This all works but the only problem is that I don't want to reload the website when redirecting the person back to the website.